# How to insert a stream at some point in another stream?

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

I'm trying to find a method to replace a portion of the content being moved by one stream with the entire contents of a second stream. I've discovered plenty of libraries to do simple string replacement, prepped, and append a stream but nothing to manipulate a stream with another stream.

**./a**

```
aaaXddd
```

**./b**

```
bbbccc
```

**./c**

```
aaabbbccc
```

**pseudo code**

```
let a = createFileReadStream('./a')
let b = createFileReadStream('./b')
let c = createFileWriteStream('./c')
a.pipe(insert('X', b)).pipe(c)
```

How can I insert the entire content of a stream into another stream?